# How to write this query to avoid cartesian product?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, cartesian-product

I want to create a CSV export for orders showing the warehouse_id where each order_item had shipped from, if available.

For brevity, here is the pertinent schema:

```
create table o (id integer);
```

orders have many order_items:

```
create table oi (id integer, o_id integer, sku text, quantity integer);
```

For each order_item in the CSV we want to show a warehouse_id from where it shipped out of.  But that is not stored in order_items.  It is stored in the shipment.

An order can be split up into many shipments from potentially from different warehouses.

```
create table s (id integer, o_id integer, warehouse_id integer);
```

shipments have many shipment items too:

```
create table si (id integer, s_id integer, oi_id integer, quantity_shipped integer);
```

How do I extract the warehouse_id for each order_item, given that warehouse_id is on the shipment and not every order has shipped yet (may not have a shipment record or shipment_items).

We are doing something like this (simplified):

```
select oi.sku, s.warehouse_id from oi 
left join s on s.o_id = oi.o_id;
```

However if an order has 2 order items, let's call them sku A and B.  And that order was split into two shipments where A was shipped from warehouse '50' and then a second shipment shipped B from '200'.

What we want would be a CSV output like:

```
 sku | warehouse_id
-----|--------------
  A  |           50
  B  |          200
```

But what we get is some kind of cartesian product:

=================================

```
Here is the sample data:

select * from o;
 id
----
  1
(1 row)

select * from oi;
 id | o_id | sku | quantity
----+------+-----+----------
  1 |    1 | A   |        1
  2 |    1 | B   |        1
(2 rows)

select * from s;
 id | o_id | warehouse_id
----+------+--------------
  1 |    1 |           50
  2 |    1 |          200
(2 rows)

select * from si;
 id | s_id | oi_id
----+------+------
  1 |    1 |    1
  2 |    2 |    2
(2 rows)

select oi.sku, s.warehouse_id from oi left join s on s.o_id = oi.o_id;
 sku | warehouse_id
-----+--------------
 A   |           50
 A   |          200
 B   |           50
 B   |          200
(4 rows)
```

UPDATE ========

Per spencer, I'm adding a different example with different pk ids for more clarity.  The following is 2 example orders.  Order 2 has items A,B,C.  A,B are shipped from shipment 200, C is shipped from shipment 201.  Order 3 has 2 items E and A.  E is not yet shipped and A is shipped twice out of the same warehouse '700', (like it was on back order).

```
# select * from o;
 id
----
  2
  3
(2 rows)

# select * from oi;
 id  | o_id | sku | quantity
-----+------+-----+----------
 100 |    2 | A   |        1
 101 |    2 | B   |        1
 102 |    2 | C   |        1
 103 |    3 | E   |        1
 104 |    3 | A   |        2
(5 rows)

# select * from s;
 id  | o_id | warehouse_id
-----+------+--------------
 200 |    2 |          700
 201 |    2 |          800
 202 |    3 |          700
 203 |    3 |          700
(4 rows)

# select * from si;
 id  | s_id | oi_id
-----+------+-------
 300 |  200 |   100
 301 |  200 |   101
 302 |  201 |   102
 303 |  202 |   104
 304 |  203 |   104
(5 rows)
```

I think this works, I use left join to keep the order_items in the report no matter if the order has shipped or not, I use group by to squash multiple shipments from the same warehouse.  I believe this is what I need.

```
# select oi.o_id, oi.id, oi.sku, s.warehouse_id from oi left join si on si.oi_id = oi.id left join s on s.id = si.s_id group by oi.o_id, oi.id, oi.sku, s.warehouse_id order by oi.o_id;
 o_id | id  | sku | warehouse_id
------+-----+-----+--------------
    2 | 102 | C   |          800
    2 | 101 | B   |          700
    2 | 100 | A   |          700
    3 | 104 | A   |          700
    3 | 103 | E   |
(5 rows)
```

Comment: When setting up examples like this (excellent job! +10) consider using different id values for the different tables, e.g. 1,2 for oi... 33,34 for s,  55,56 for si ... that makes the example easier to understand... seeing a row (1,1,1) in si can be a little confusing. It also helps avoid producing erroneous queries that appear to return correct results, but do so by accident, due to coincidental id values.

Comment: Can an Order Item with a quantity greater than 1 be split to multiple warehouses or Shipment Item records?  So say you order 2 widgets can 1 widget be shipped out of one warehouse and the other out of a different warehouse?

Comment: @Matt: excellent question. Typically, for small items, where multiple items can be included in a single shipment, the order fulfillment would prefer to send from a single warehouse, to hold down shipping costs. So, for an order of 12 items, with 10 in one warehouse, and 20 in another, probably would be filled from the warehouse with 20. But for an order large enough that it can't be filled from a single warehouse, there would need to be two shipments. The system may also have a preference to fill from a "closer" warehouse, for faster shipping.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that the specification is for a (partial) cartesian product. For items that have shipped, we could include a join to the `si` table. For order items that aren't shipped, there's a potential to ship from multiple warehouses... and that's the result the query is producing. We could add a `GROUP BY oi.id` and collapse the rows, but then there's the issue (as Matt identified) of picking out which of the multiple warehouse rows to return a single value from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order items that have shipped ...

```
SELECT oi.id
     , oi.sku
     , s.warehouse_id
  FROM oi
  JOIN si ON si.oi_id = oi.id
  JOIN s  ON s.id     = si.s_id
```

Order items that haven't yet shipped, using anti-join to exclude rows where there is a matching row in si

```
SELECT oi.id
     , oi.sku
     , s.warehouse_id
  FROM oi
  JOIN s ON s.o_id = oi.o_id      -- fk to fk shortcut join
    -- anti-join
  LEFT
  JOIN si ON si.oi_id = oi.id
 WHERE si.oi_id IS NULL
```

But this will still produce a (partial) Cartesian product.  We can add a GROUP BY clause to collapse the rows...

```
 GROUP BY si.oi_id
```

This doesn't avoid producing an intermediate cartesian product; the addition of the GROUP BY clause collapses the set.  But it's indeterminate which of matching rows from `s` column values will be returned from.

The two queries could be combined with a UNION ALL operation. If I did that, I'd likely add a discriminator column (an additional column in each query with different values, which would tell which query returned a row.)

This set might meet the specification outlined in the OP question. But I don't think this is really the set that needs to be returned. Figuring out which warehouse an item should ship from may involve several factors... total quantity ordered, quantity available in each warehouse, can order be fulfilled from one warehouse, which warehouse is closer to delivery destination, etc.

I don't want to leave anyone with the impression that this query is really a "fix" for the cartesian product problem... this query just hides a bigger problem.

Comment: first you do a good deal of explanation and breaking code down by steps from uderstandign which is great and I commend you on that!  I am curious though about where are you wanting to add "GROUP BY si.oi_id" to in your code neither of the queries have si.oi_id in the select and actually in the second it will always be null. so I am not sure where you are going with that.  The other key I have seen in your comments has been to account for items not shipped.  Which I am not positive your assumption that assignment to order in shipments table s means that will be the shipping warehouse

Comment: then there is that the OP states "showing the warehouse_id where each order_item had shipped from, if available." so I read that as OP doesn't care if item hasn't shipped but if it has get the warehouse.  you have a ton of good points as far as a pick pack ship system but I think you may have over thought this one.  good detail and information though so I think you have certainly given OP ways to consider and solve this and other issues! cheers + 1

Comment: @Matt: You raise some very good points. Entirely possible I over thought it. A good part of my career has involved thinking about problems like this, identifying entities, relationships between entities, attributes, 3NF (every attribute is dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key), in terms of database design to fit specific (and probable) use cases, asking appropriate questions, including a lot of "what if" questions. e.g. "what if an order requires more items than available from a single warehouse"... to make sure the design (tables, constraints and queries will work.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `si` table:

```
select oi.sku, s.warehouse_id
from si join
     oi
     on si.o_id = oi.o_id join
     s
     on s.s_id = si.s_id;
```

`si` seems to be the proper junction table between the tables.  I'm not sure why there is another join key that doesn't use it.

Comment: This gets the warehouse for items that have been shipped, but I think the issue OP has, the question OP asked, is how to also get warehouse for items that have *not yet* shipped. For `oi` (order item) where there isn't a row in `s` (shipment) and/or `si` (shipment_item).